# mean till 25 percentile for rows of an array containing nan

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, nan, array-broadcasting

I have a 2d array x, with each row having a different number of nan values:

```
array([[   nan, -0.355, -0.036, ...,    nan,    nan],
       [   nan, -0.341, -0.047, ...,    nan,  0.654],
       [  .016, -1.147, -0.667, ...,    nan,    nan],
       ..., 
       [   nan,  0.294, -0.235, ...,    0.65,   nan]])
```

Given this array, for each row, I want to calculate the mean of all values within first 25 percentile. I am doing the following:

```
limit = np.nanpercentile(x, 25, axis=1) # output 1D array
ans = np.nanmean(x * (x < limit[:,None]), axis=1)
```

But this is giving wrong results - specifically the count (np.nansum/np.nanmean) remains the same no matter what percentile I choose because the comparison produces zero where it is not true, and gets counted as a valid value for mean. I cant simply use `x[x>limit[:,None]]` because that gives a 1D array and I need a 2D result.

I solved it by following:

```
f = x.copy()
f[f > limit[:,None]] = np.nan
ans = np.nanmean(f, axis=1)
```

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Do you mean `limit`, where you've written `low`? If so, then I think that's exactly the procedure I'd adopt too. What manner of a better approach are you looking for?

Comment: thanks, yes that is the limit. Preferably want an approach without too many intermediate steps because with this one, I need to create a copy every time i want another percentile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** You could create a mask of invalid ones, which would be `NaNs` from original array and the mask from `f > limit[:,None]`. Then, use this mask to perform `np.nanmean` equivalent approach by consider the valid ones only with `masking`. The benefit with using `masks/boolean arrays` would be in terms of memory as it would occupy 8 times less memory than floating pt arrays. Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
# Create mask of non-NaNs and thresholded ones
mask = ~np.isnan(x) & (x <= limit[:,None])

# Get the row, col indices. Use the row indices for bin-based summing and
# finally averaging by using those indices to get the group lengths.
r,c = np.where(mask)
out = np.bincount(r,x[mask])/np.bincount(r)
```

**Approach #2 :** We could also use `np.add.reduceat` which be helpful here as the bins are already sorted as per the masking. So, a bit more efficient would be like so -

```
# Get the valid mask as before
mask = ~np.isnan(x) & (x <= limit[:,None])

# Get valid row count. Use np.add.reduceat to perform grouped summations
# at intervals separated by row indices.
rowc = mask.sum(1)
out = np.add.reduceat(x[mask],np.append(0,rowc[:-1].cumsum()))/rowc
```

**Benchmarking**

Function defintions -

```
def original_app(x, limit):
    f = x.copy()
    f[f > limit[:,None]] = np.nan
    ans = np.nanmean(f, axis=1) 
    return ans

def proposed1_app(x, limit):
    mask = ~np.isnan(x) & (x <= limit[:,None])
    r,c = np.where(mask)
    out = np.bincount(r,x[mask])/np.bincount(r)
    return out

def proposed2_app(x, limit):
    mask = ~np.isnan(x) & (x <= limit[:,None])
    rowc = mask.sum(1)
    out = np.add.reduceat(x[mask],np.append(0,rowc[:-1].cumsum()))/rowc
    return out
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [402]: # Setup inputs
     ...: x = np.random.randn(400,500)
     ...: x.ravel()[np.random.randint(0,x.size,x.size//4)] = np.nan # Half as NaNs
     ...: limit = np.nanpercentile(x, 25, axis=1)
     ...: 

In [403]: np.allclose(original_app(x, limit),proposed1_app(x, limit))
Out[403]: True

In [404]: np.allclose(original_app(x, limit),proposed2_app(x, limit))
Out[404]: True

In [405]: %timeit original_app(x, limit)
100 loops, best of 3: 5 ms per loop

In [406]: %timeit proposed1_app(x, limit)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.02 ms per loop

In [407]: %timeit proposed2_app(x, limit)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.18 ms per loop
```